# How to retrieve shared preference value without refreshing app after edit

Tags: java, android, refresh, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activities: main.java and persistentvalue.java

I save my value at persistentvalue.java and retrieve the shared preference value at main.java.

persistentvalue.java is another activity as a pop up page instead of a new page.
so whenever i press the saved button it will automatically go back to main.java without refreshing main.java activity

I am only able to retrieve the newly updated/edited shared preference when I quit the application and start it again.

How do I retrieve the shared preference value that has just been updated/edited without refreshing the main activity? Because when i put intent from persistentvalue.java to main.java , my app crashes.

Appreciate some help here.

CODE:

persistentvalue.java

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("text1", editText1.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

main.java

```
prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

text1 = prefs.getString("text1", "");

showText.setText(text1);
```

persistentvalue.java is actually a pop up screen
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
        android:name="com.example.project.main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name="com.example.project.persistentvalue"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.project.main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.project.main" />
    </activity>
```

I am able to retrieve the value at main.java but I have to quit the application and start it again so just wondering if there is a way to retrieve without refreshing the activity.

when I put intent app crashes, the logcat as shown below:

```
10-19 03:53:35.660: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-217
10-19 03:53:35.660: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Can we see some code? The logcat would also help.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are retrieving the value in `onCreate()` when you should be using `onResume()` or `onStart()`.

Comment: updated the code and logcat.

Comment: You need to post the entire stack trace, not just the first line and also the method where you read the preference value.  Did you read my comment?

Comment: @Simon: yes i did it using onCreate(). It works now using onResume(). Thanks a lot for the help :)